# Disable CSRF / CORS in Spring Boot: Spring security 5.7 and SAML

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using a Spring Boot application with the latest stable versions of Spring Boot and Sprign Security. I am doing authentication with an ADFS IDP using SAML2.
That works fine for all GET requests. Now I need to use PUT and POST and therfore I'd like to disable csrf.

With this pease of code I tried to disable csrf:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().and().cors().disable();
    }

}
```

But when doing this the complete SAML Authentication gets lost and no Single-Sign-On and so on is performed.
I am using SAML2 by configuration:

```
spring:
  security:
    saml2:
      relyingparty:
        registration:
          DemoApp: 
            entity-id: urn:id:demo-app
            identityprovider:
              entity-id: "http://adfs.local/adfs/services/trust"
              metadata-uri: "https://adfs.local/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml"     
              singlesignon:
                url: "https://adfs.local/adfs/ls"
                sign-request: true
```

How do I disable csrf and keep the SAML2 things working?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### The Java configuration below will disable CSRF protection in Spring security 5.7

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable());
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

For more details follow the link below

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/csrf.html#servlet-csrf-configure-disable

Comment: Make sure when referring to links, you include a relevant snippet in your comment. If a link dies or is updated, the answer may not make sense for future readers!

Answer (score 1):

WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is deprecated. Use a SecurityFilterChain Bean to configure HttpSecurity or a WebSecurityCustomizer Bean to configure WebSecurity. Try this

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .cors().disable();      
    return http.build();
}
```

Comment: You can use the same builder to override spring boot autoconfig 
`.authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated()).saml2Login(withDefaults());`